# Binding two columns into single drop down

Tags: vb.net

I want to bind the two columns into single drop-down list. In my table data like that,

Id.    Mobile1.       Mobile2

1. ```
   89867889.      893922233
   ```
2. ```
   37374849.      494940404
   ```

I want data like
Select mobile1,mobile2 from table where I'd ='1'

So result in drop-down mobile2 and Mobile2

Please anybody have solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the term "drop-down list" generaically or do you actually mean a Web Forms `DropDownList` control? How about adding all the relevant tags so that we don't need to guess or ask what should be provided by default?

Comment: Regardless, you probably can't do that anyway, whatever the control. You might be able to create a custom control but probably not with a standard control. You need to process the data first so a single property/column in the data source contains everything you want to display in the control. Exactly how to do that depends on the data source but the UI is irrelevant. It's likely a simple case of concatenating two strings in a loop, neither of which is a task that you should need us to explain to you. When you've considered the problem and made an attempt, then we can talk again.